# How to Properly Authenticate Google Vision API Using Polymer

Tags: polymer-2.x, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to run a test on the `Google Cloud Vision API` to see how it fares to the client side `Shape Detection API`.

I am hoping to `POST` JSON with a base64 encoded image and get image text and barcodes returned.

I have created a `GCP` project and API key per the tutorial at (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/before-you-begin), but am getting an 401 error when trying to make requests.

> error: {code: 401,…}
>   code: 401
>   message: "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."
>   status: "UNAUTHENTICATED"

The request is written in Polymer 2.x as follows:

```
<iron-ajax id="googleApi" 
  body="[[request]]" 
  content-type="application/json" 
  handle-as="json"
  headers$='{"Authorization": "Bearer [[GOOGLE_API_KEY]]"}' 
  last-response="{{response}}" 
  loading="{{loading}}"
  method="post" 
  url="https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate">
</iron-ajax>
```

...

```
GOOGLE_API_KEY: {
  type: String,
  value: 'AIza0101010110100101101010'
}
```

...

```
getRequest(image) {
  let encoded = image.toString('base64');
  this.request = {
    "requests": [{
      "image": {
        "content": encoded
      },
      "features": [{
        "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
        "maxResults": 1
      }]
    }]
  };
  let request = this.$.googleApi.generateRequest();
  request.completes.then(req => {
    console.log('submission complete');
    console.log(this.response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

How do I resolve this authentication error?

It is an account admin issue? Improperly formatted code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization header is not needed, so the request should be in the form of:

```
<iron-ajax id="googleApi" 
  body="[[request]]" 
  content-type="application/json" 
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{response}}" 
  loading="{{loading}}"
  method="post" 
  url="https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=[[GOOGLE_API_KEY]]">
</iron-ajax>
```